# Completing Coordinate transformation?

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, geodesy, vertical-transformation

I have two airborne lidar datasets and, for purposes of comparing change between the two, would like to standardize the vertical and horizontal coordinate information for each. The plan is to transform the horizontal/vertical system of the 1st dataset to match that of the 2nd dataset. Here are systems for each:

*1st dataset:*
**Year** - 2010-2011
**Horizontal** - NAD83 UTM 4N
**Vertical** - GRS80 Ellipsoid

*2nd dataset:*
**Year** - 2017
**Horizontal** - ITRF00 projected into UTM 4N
**Vertical** - NAVD88 (Geoid12A)

I simply am not well versed in geodesy enough to know how to proceed in completing this transformation. I have access to Blue Marble Geographic Calculator and NOAA's Vertical Datum Transformation tool.

How should I proceed here?

**I should clarify my issue is not with the usability of any of the software packages. Rather, I'm confused about the actual best practices for the conversions to make (i.e. converting from lidar shot at an ellipsoid to those referenced to NAVD88 with a particular geoid12A).**

Comment: With NOAA's tool, you should attempt to follow the steps given in https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html#step33 first, then, explain what you stuck with.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my issue however is not with the usability of any of the software packages. Rather, I'm confused about the actual best practices for the conversions to make (i.e. converting from lidar shot at an ellipsoid to those referenced to NAVD88 with a particular geoid12A)